# Is there a way to prevent comments from being rendered in Rails views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I was wondering if there is a way to prevent comments from being rendered in Rails views (other than deleting them). The comments I have in my views are mostly intended for developers and I don't want users to be able to read them in the  html. Can I set some rendering option that strips out all of the comments?

I am using haml, if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different types of comments you can leave in the views:

1) HTML comments which can always be seen by users if they view the source:

```
<!-- this is a comment -->
```

2) Ruby comments which will be interpreted as comments on the server and not sent as HTML

HAML:

```
-# This is a comment
```

ERB:

```
<%# This is a comment %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Render your comments in the ruby context :

```
#haml
- #bla bla bla

#html
<% #bla bla bla %>
```